# Current induced in a superconducting coil

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Does the magnitude of current induced in a shorted superconducting coil depend on the external flux's rate of change $\frac{d\Phi_{EXT}}{dt}$ ?

Assume that initially the flux through the coil is zero and the initial current circulating in that coil is zero, too, but at some later time, an external flux source attempts to change the flux threading that shorted ideal coil to $\Phi_{EXT}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the total flux through the superconducting loop remains constant at $0$ (the reason for this is that any change in flux requires a nonzero emf around the loop, which requires in infinite current, so magnetic flux through the loop cannot change), the flux from the self-inductance $L$ of the loop must be equal and opposite to the external flux. We conclude that $I=\frac{\Phi}{L}$.

To answer the question, no: current only depends on the flux, not the rate of change.

Comment: Note this phenomenon, described by @DanDan0101 is independent on how fast the flux changes; it can be days, it can be nanoseconds. If the changes were on picosecond scale, the corresponding energy ($\hbar/\tau$) could get similar to the pseudogap and some induced energy could be lost in the semiconductor.

Comment: What physical law says that the flux generated by the self-inductance of the coil must be equal and opposite to the external flux?  When I read about the Lenz Law on Wikipedia, it only talks about the opposite DIRECTION of the induced current. It says nothing about its magnitude being such, that it opposes the entire external flux. It also says that the Lenz law is not a quantitative law.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson superconducting loop has frozen magnetic flux, because it is superconductive. Any external induced electric field is counteracted by induced electric field of the loop and the result is total electric field inside is zero.

Comment: @Jan. Why are you bringing up electric field when coils are concerned primarily with the magnetic field ? Capacitors work with electric field, don't they?

Comment: Because total electric field equals zero, hence magnetic flux cannot change. This is Faraday's law of EM induction.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson We're considering the loop integral of electric field around the superconducting loop. It had better be zero, or else we would have infinite current!

Comment: @Jan But the Faraday's law of induction is not about the induced current at all. It is about the induced emf or ℰ = -dΦ/dt.  I understand DanDan's reply about the loop integral, but that integral is nowhere to be found in the Faraday's law.

Comment: @DanDan0101 I have upvoted but not accepted your answer because it does not answer the original question directly, i.e. "Y/N" to "Does the magnitude of current induced in a shorted superconducting coil depend on... ?"  The answer implies "No" as it provides justification for the "No" and the formula for the current `I=...` given at the end does not include the rate of change of flux term in it. So it seems like a good answer but an indirect one.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson The loop integral of electric field is equal to the induced emf. It certainly appears in Faraday's Law. I'll update my answer to make it a little bit more explicit.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson I didn't say it was about induced current.

Comment: @DanDan0101: Shouldn't the expression for induced current have a negative sign to symbolize that the flux generated by the induced current opposes the external flux. i.e.:  $i=-\frac{\Phi}{L}$.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Sure, but all depends on which way you think positive current is anyways. Note that for inductors, often the sign convention $\Phi=LI$ is used.

Comment: @DanDan0101: I think the sign should convey that the counter-flux $\Phi_L$ generated by the induced current, is opposite to the external flux $\Phi_{Ext}$ so when $i(t_0)=0$ and $R=0$  then  $\Phi_L=-\Phi_{Ext}$ .  See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnW4A.jpg  If you agree then please add the sign to your solution.

Comment: @DanDan0101: Please clear up the issue of the sign in your solution. It has been 2 days and this lack of clarity affects the answer to the following question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588167/complete-expression-for-current-induced-in-a-conductive-loop